# For Jenkins User Chrome UI is not opening

Tags: jenkins

I tried setting up Jenkins in two ways :

1. Just one Jenkins Master
2. With a Master and slave configured in another machine.

In both cases, the Chrome UI is not getting opened. When I try to run scripts in Chrome - headless mode its working.

I executed the command :

```
su Jenkins
google-chrome
```

I got an error -

```
No protocol specified

(google-chrome:13404): Gtk-WARNING **: 10:26:05.136: cannot open display: :0
```

Any idea Why this is happening. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's happening because the jenkins user is not allowed to communicate with the GUI.

I don't think it's a nice solution to allow another user access the frontend but if you're willing to proceed the solution is to execute the following with your main user:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:Jenkins
```

relevant src:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193827/what-is-display-0
- https://superuser.com/questions/85818/allow-only-one-extra-user-to-access-the-display